# Why ipx does not work for external domain

Tags: nuxt.js

i am trying to setup @nuxt/image with ipx provider. But for an external image, the external URL is written to the srcset without the "/_ipx" prefix. If the picture is local, then the prefix appears, but the picture is not displayed. What am I missing in the setup?

sanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-wildflower-tj3vlr?file=/pages/index.vue:505-681

Answer (score 0):

Try adding into your nuxt.config.js(ts) file the next lines :

```
image: {
    domains: [
      'upload.wikimedia.org'
    ]
  },
```